# Make mouse events detectable on whole node stack

Tags: java, javafx

I have problem where I have `BorderPane` in which center's there is `TabPane` with `Tabs` that have various other `Nodes` (say another `BorderPane` for example).

When I try to for example use:

```
parentBorderPane.setOnMouseDragged(e -> System.out.println("DRAGGING"));
parentBorderPane.setOnMouseMoved(e -> System.out.println("MOVING"));
```

...events never occur (I can catch them on currently opened `Tab's` content, but that's not what I want).

I require to know when such events occur in BOTH places, (1st event goes through content of `Tab`, then through containing `TabPane`, then through main parent `BorderPane`). So I can't use (on any of children):

```
this.setMouseTransparent(true);
```

How can this be solved?

***EDIT***

Let me add that main problem is with `TabPane` - its the one that doesn't pass events to next node in stack.

***EDIT 2***

```
public class T extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        Scene scene = new Scene(this.working()); // change to this.problem();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private BorderPane working()
    {
        BorderPane main = new BorderPane();
        main.setPrefSize(800, 600);
        main.setOnMouseMoved(e -> System.out.println("MOVING ON MAIN"));

        BorderPane sub = new BorderPane();
        sub.setOnMouseMoved(e -> System.out.println("MOVING ON SUB"));
        main.setCenter(sub);

        return main;
    }

    private BorderPane problem()
    {
        BorderPane main = new BorderPane();
        main.setPrefSize(800, 600);
        main.setOnMouseMoved(e -> System.out.println("MOVING ON MAIN"));

        BorderPane sub = new BorderPane();
        sub.setOnMouseMoved(e -> System.out.println("MOVING ON SUB"));
        main.setCenter(sub);

        TabPane tabs = new TabPane();
        tabs.setOnMouseMoved(e -> System.out.println("MOVING ON TABS"));
        sub.setCenter(tabs);

        return main;
    }
}
```

`working()` - Normal `Panes` stacked on each other will work as they should (pass events from top to bottom of stack).

`problem()` - Because `TabPane` is sub-class of Control (which I am currently investagating), it stops mouse events and doesn't let parents see them.

Comment: Showing us a minimal working program displaying the problem will help us identifying it faster.

Comment: @JKostikiadis Added example code.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution - instead of trying to receive event durnig bubble-up phase (child->parent behind) where `Control` (parent class of `TabPane`) consumes it, I can use [event filters](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm) and catch event before its consumed.

Comment: Also a great post with a lot of useful information can been found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24617790/4167500