# JavaFX layout moves when button is clicked

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

This is a gif of my problem:

[image]

As you can see, the button resizes (elevates? and it moves it's outer layout with itself.

This is the hierarchy:

```
StackPane
    Group // for other content
    Group // The make hbox "wrap-content"
        HBox  // For the 2 buttons
            JfxToggleButton  // "This is test"
            JfxButton    // "Restart" button
```

The only code to add is that I am positioning the HBox's Group top right of the StackPane, like this:

```
StackPane.setAlignment(hboxGroup, Pos.TOP_RIGHT)
```

Only `StackPane` has this issue, `BorderPane` does not have it.
The reason I am using `StackPane` is because I want to have **the controls on top of the main content**.

`ToggleButton` and `HBox` have padding.

Actually, padding and alignment do not matter, since the `HBox` moves relatively regardless.

Btw, I am using [jfonix library](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) for button styling.

Thanks for your help.

Edit.:

For those who contribute this problem to JFoenix, this is the same with standard JavaFX controls: (the jump still occurs, only less noticable)

[image]

Compared to what I mentioned above, where the`Hbox`has it's place in the top of a `BorderPane`, the jump does not happen:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the padding on the button changes when it is selected, causing the layout to change... Are you using your own CSS for this?

Comment: @James_D the bigger padding might make it more visible, but the problem is that it does not stick to it's place. 

Also, I am not using my own css.

Answer (score 0):

I realized `AnchorPane` does not have this problem.

So this the final layout hierarchy:

```
StackPane
    Group // Content behind
    AnchorPane // That restricts movement, keeps the buttons in place
        Group   // That keeps the background only around the buttons
            HBox // Keeps the buttons next to each other
                ToggleButton
                Button
```

So I ended up with [the problem that `AnchorPane` does not let clicks through.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607969/mouse-events-get-ignored-on-the-underlying-layer) Which is fixed by setting the `AnchorPane`

```
anchorPane.setPickOnBounds(false);
```